# Undesired behavior when preloading and ordering a has_many :through association

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

If we have 3 schemas: ChatRoom, User, and Message

```
ChatRoom.ex
schema "chat_rooms" do
  has_many(:users, User)
  has_many(:messages, through: [:users, :messages])
end
```

Is there an established way with Ecto to "Get a chat room, and all of the messages of associated users sorted by some field on the message"?

I originally was trying to simply get a chatroom and `preload` it with all of its messages sorted by `message.inserted_at`, and was ok with having it do that in two queries (and understand how to do that in a single query combining `join` and `preload`), but when it comes time to sort by a value on the has_many :through resource, it seems to apply that same sort to the middle association (in this example, user).

Example issue: So if ChatRoom A has two users in it (user1 joined first, user2 joined second), and we had the message sequence of:

- user1: "hi"
- user2: "hello"
- user1: "goodbye"
- user2: "farewell"

If I did:

```
sorted_message_query = from(message in Message, order_by: message.inserted_at)

from(chat_room in ChatRoom,
  where: chat_room.id == ^chat_room_id,
  preload: [messages: ^sorted_message_query]
)
```

The `messages` result on the `chat_room` would actually be listed like:

1. user1's "hi"
2. user1's "goodbye"
3. user2's "hello"
4. user2's "farewell"

which is clearly not the goal. How do you sort a preloaded query in Ecto without having that apply to the join resource?

Comment: I can get around this by just joining chat_rooms with users and messages, and then order by messages.inserted_at and selecting just what I want (a couple attributes from chat_rooms and all of messages etc), but I was mostly wondering if there was a more "Ecto-y" way with the preloading binding magic etc

Comment: I confirmed Ecto is applying the sorting preload query to the user_id on the messages table in addition to the desired inserted_at, this is definitely what is causing this undesired behavior, wonder if Jose or someone could explain the reasoning `SELECT m0."id", m0."content", m0."user_id", m0."inserted_at", m0."updated_at", m0."user_id" FROM "messages" AS m0 WHERE (m0."user_id" = ANY($1)) ORDER BY m0."user_id", m0."inserted_at" [[<<...>>, <<...>>]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am not sure why I was finding this so confusing, total brain fart kind of day. Explicitly joining both associations and then preloading those existing joins did it for me:

```
  from chat_room in ChatRoom,
    where: chat_room.id == ^chat_room_id,
    join: user in assoc(chat_room, :users),
    left_join: message in assoc(user, :messages),
    preload: [users: user, messages: message],
    order_by: message.inserted_at
```